# how to assign a list from xml through linq

Tags: xml, linq

i have one xml.  xml have list of purchase order.inside that purchase order i have list of customer.so through below code i got all element except that list of customer.how can i assign that list from xml to my list in the class.anybody can sort it out.

```
 var ItemDet = from results in doc1.Descendants("PurchaseOrderClass")
                              select new PurchaseOrderClass
                              {
                                  Vendor_Name = results.Element("Vendor_Name").Value.ToString(),
                                  ItemCode = results.Descendants("ItemCode").First().Value.ToString(),
                                  Quantity = Int32.Parse(results.Descendants("Quantity").First().Value),
                                  Price = Int32.Parse(results.Element("Price").Value),
                                  Discount = Int32.Parse(results.Descendants("Discount").First().Value),
                                  TotalAmount = Int32.Parse(results.Descendants("TotalAmount").First().Value),
                                  DeliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(results.Descendants("DeliveryDate").First().Value),
                                  PO_Number = Int32.Parse(results.Descendants("PO_Number").First().Value),
                                  //CusList= List<Customer> (results.Descendants("Customer")).ToList(),

                              };
```

Comment: Can you show sample of xml you are parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line by something like that (hard to do better without your xml and class structure).

```
CustList = results.Descendants("Customer")
                  .Select(m => new Customer {
                       LastName = m.Element("LastName").Value,
                       FirstName = m.Element("FirstName").Value,
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use casting elements to `string`, `int` or `DateTime` instead of getting `Value` property. Your query should look like this:

```
 var ItemDet = 
       from o in doc1.Descendants("PurchaseOrderClass")
       select new PurchaseOrderClass
       {
            Vendor_Name = (string)o.Element("Vendor_Name"),
            ItemCode = (string)o.Element("ItemCode"),
            Quantity = (int)o.Element("Quantity"),
            Price = (int)o.Element("Price"),
            Discount = (int)o.Element("Discount"),
            TotalAmount = (int)o.Element("TotalAmount"),
            DeliveryDate = (DateTime)o.Element("DeliveryDate"),
            PO_Number = (int)o.Element("PO_Number"),
            CusList= o.Descendants("Customer")
                      .Select(c => new Customer {
                          // parse properties like
                          // Name = (string)c.Element("Name")
                      }).ToList()
       };
```